# how to solve tunneling socket could not be established error?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

When I issue below command, I'm getting this error. please help me to solve.

> heroku run bash

```
Running bash on myapp... !!!
 ▸    ECONNRESET: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
 !   Error in heroku-run:
 !   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.rollbar.com api.rollbar.com:443
 !   See /home/simon/.heroku/error.log for more info.
```

Note: I have `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

certainly your proxy doesn't allowed to connect with heroku server... Please try with other system or change the proxy and try again...